# Is it possible to recover from panic on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm wondering if it's possible to recover from a panic. It seems GAE has it's own [panic recovery](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/internal/api.go) mechanism but I can't find any hook to handle it on my app.

Comment: Suspect you just need to `recover()` in each handler (possibly by wrapping them in a panic-recovery function). (Sorry, not familiar enough with GAE, etc. to actually give you code.)

Answer (score 1):

Handlers in an AppEngine webapp are registered in the same way as would be in a normal Go application. You just don't have to call `http.ListenAndServe()` explicitly (because it will be by the platform), and handler registration happens in an `init()` function (not in `main()`).

Having said that, the same panic-recover wrapping works on AppEngine too, and unfortunately there is no other, better way.

Take a look at this example: it uses a function registered with [`HandleFunc()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandleFunc) and a [`Handler`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) registered with [`Handle()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handle) to handle 2 URL patterns, but both intentionally panics (they refuse to serve):

```
func myHandleFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    panic("I'm myHandlerFunc and I refuse to serve!")
}

type MyHandler int

func (m *MyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    panic("I'm MyHandler and I refuse to serve!")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/myfunc", myHandleFunc)
    http.Handle("/myhandler", new(MyHandler))

    panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Directing your browser to `http://localhost:8080/myfunc` and `http://localhost:8080/myhandler` results in HTTP 500 status: internal server error (or an empty response depending on where you check it).

The general idea is to use `recover` to "catch" the panics from handlers ([spec: Handling panics](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics)). We can "wrap" handle functions or Handlers in a way that we first register a [`defer`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) statement which is called even if the rest of the function panics, and in which we recover from the panicing state.

See these 2 functions:

```
func protectFunc(hf func(http.ResponseWriter,
    *http.Request)) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer func() {
            r := recover()
            if r != nil {
                // hf() paniced, we just recovered from it.
                // Handle error somehow, serve custom error page.
                w.Write([]byte("Something went bad but I recovered and sent this!"))
            }
        }()
        hf(w, r)
    }
}

func protectHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer func() {
            r := recover()
            if r != nil {
                // h.ServeHTTP() paniced, we just recovered from it.
                // Handle error somehow, serve custom error page.
                w.Write([]byte("Something went bad but I recovered and sent this!"))
            }
        }()
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

The first one takes a function and returns one which calles the one we passed but recovers from panicing state if one was initiated.

The second one takes a `Handler` and returns another `Handler` which similarly calls the passed one but also handles panics and restores normal execution.

Now if we register handler functions and `Handler`s protected by these methods, the registered handlers will never panic (assuming the code after restoring normal execution does not panic):

```
http.HandleFunc("/myfunc-protected", protectFunc(myHandleFunc))
http.Handle("/myhandler-protected", protectHandler(new(MyHandler)))
```

Visiting `http://localhost:8080/myfunc-protected` and `http://localhost:8080/myhandler-protected` URLs resuls in HTTP 200 status (OK) with the message:

```
Something went bad but I recovered and sent this!
```

Comment: For some reasons it works when I recover from my own panics (i.e. like in the example you provided) but when some google packages (e.g.  google cloud storage  [0]  trying to write using a nil / incorrect context ) panics the program doesn't recover anymore. Any idea why? http://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/storage#NewReader

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat The protecting mechanism presented above can only recover from panics initiated from the `ServeHTTP()` method. I guess the panics that you can't catch are not called from within the `ServeHttp()` method but potentially from other goroutines (that may or may not be started from within your `ServeHTTP()` method).